# WPF how to convert FlowDocument BGImage to FixedDocument and show it in DocumentViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a FlowDocument with Background image. Currently it does not display properly in FlowDocumentReader since the background image stays centered when document is scrolled up and down. How to convert this FlowDocument to FixedDocument and display it in DocumentViewer, so the background image will be fixed as well ?

I use the conversion logic from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362918/how-to-convert-flowdocument-to-fixeddocument-using-flowdocuments-idocumentpagin). But it does not display the FlowDocument.Background image.

```
    private FixedDocument convert(FlowDocument flowDocument)
    {
        if (flowDocument == null)
            return null;
        var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
        var package = Package.Open(new MemoryStream(), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        var packUri = new Uri("pack://temp.xps");
        PackageStore.RemovePackage(packUri);
        PackageStore.AddPackage(packUri, package);
        var xps = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.NotCompressed, packUri.ToString());
        XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xps).Write(paginator);
        FixedDocument doc = xps.GetFixedDocumentSequence().References[0].GetDocument(true);
        return doc;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> I have a FlowDocument with Background image. Currently it does not display properly in FlowDocumentReader since the background image stays centered when document is scrolled up and down.

Not exactly an answer to your specific question, but to avoid this, set [`ImageBrush.ViewportUnits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewportunits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [`BrushMappingMode.Absolute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushmappingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Then, set  [`ImageBrush.Viewport`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the desired dimension of your background image:

```
        <FlowDocumentReader ViewingMode="Scroll">
            <FlowDocument>
               <FlowDocument.Background>
                    <ImageBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Fill" Viewport="0,0,1000,400" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                            <!--Image source here...-->
                        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                    </ImageBrush>
```

Optionally set [`ImageBrush.Stretch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`Stretch.Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to fill the your specified viewport with your image, and set [`ImageBrush.TileMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [`TileMode.Tile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make the background image repeat.

Comment: Thank you for the viewport setting, but still cannot print the Background Image...

Comment: I got it. What you have is the correct workaround. Once ImageBrush is set, the FlowDocument could be printed.